# List of distinct years between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to retrieve the list of distinct years between two dates.

For example, from `25/12/2006` to `14/11/2013`, the result should look like:

```
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
```

Is this possible in SQL Server ?

Comment: How is this not a real question?  It's hard to see how this question could be clarified.

Comment: Agree - the question is precise, concise and to the point

Comment: Baffled at the closure..

Comment: Agreed, I've voted to re-open also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A date like `1/2/2013` is ambiguous: depending on the regional setting, it can be either Feb 1st, or Jan 2nd.  So it's a good idea to use the `YYYY-MM-DD` date format when talking to the datebase.

You can generate a list of numbers using a recursive CTE:

```
; with  CTE as
        (
        select  datepart(year, '2006-12-25') as yr
        union all
        select  yr + 1
        from    CTE
        where   yr < datepart(year, '2013-11-14')
        )
select  yr
from    CTE
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4472/0)

Comment: In fact, `YYYY-MM-DD` is also ambiguous: `set language french; select cast('2001-12-14' as datetime);` According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), `YYYYMMDD` is the appropriate short format for `datetime` constants.

Comment: @Andomar . . . I think you understood the question correctly and gave a really good answer.  I voted to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on SQL Server 2008

```
declare @smaller_date date = convert(date, '25/12/2006', 103)
declare @larger_date date = convert(date, '14/11/2013', 103)
declare @diff int
select @diff = DATEDIFF(YY, @smaller_date,  @larger_date)

;with sequencer(runner) as(
select 0 
union all
select sequencer.runner + 1 from sequencer
where runner < @diff
)
select YEAR(@smaller_date) + runner from sequencer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].Fn_Interval 
(   
    @p1 datetime2, 
    @p2 datetime2
)
RETURNS @dt TABLE 
(
    YearValue int not null
)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @start as int
    declare @end as int

    set @start = DATEPART(year, @p1);
    set @end = DATEPART(year, @p2);

    while (@start <= @end)
    begin
        INSERT @dt
        SELECT @start;
        set @start = @start + 1;
    end

    RETURN;
END
```

Open a Query and try:

```
declare @p1 as datetime2;
declare @p2 as datetime2;

set @p1 = '2013-12-31';
set @p2 = '2020-05-05';

select *
from dbo.Fn_Interval(@p1, @p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html). Then you simply query the years:

```
select distinct YearNumber
from dbo.Calendar
where [Date] between '20061225' and '20131114'
order by YearNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

Since OP’s example is literally a small set of values, I’d figure I’d throw in an answer that doesn’t rely on recursion/loops or creating additional objects such as functions/date-tables. It simply uses the Top clause.

Tested on SQL Server 2016

```
DECLARE @startYear smallint;
SET @startYear = YEAR ('2006-12-25');

DECLARE @endYear smallint;
SET @endYear = YEAR('2013-11-14');

-- Top uses expression to bring in N number of rows. The (@startYear - 1) is to retain the start year
SELECT TOP (@endYear - (@startYear - 1)) COUNT([object_id]) OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) + (@startYear - 1) -- Add initial start year to Count 
FROM sys.all_objects;
```

Hope that's a different take.