# Insert date range in a temp table without loop and cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table where I need to insert all the years of between two date range. for example if date range is from 2010 to 2018 then table will have

```
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
```

any one have any query where i can insert these values into the temp table without using the while loop or cursor.

Comment: you can use CTE

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857539/list-of-distinct-years-between-two-dates

Comment: Why not use a while loop or a cursor? Anywyay, any information on populating tally tables will give you an answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Because loops and cursors are something one should avoid if ever possible?

Comment: Not for nine records.. or for a learning experience

Comment: if its just a one time thing or if the data will always be just a few records than there is no problem with using a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Recursive CTE. Like this

```
DECLARE @Min INT=2010,@Max INT=2018
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        MyData = @MIn

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MyData = MyData+1
        FROM CTE
            WHERE MyData < @Max
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is an ad-hoc tally table

```
Declare @R1 int = 2010
Declare @R2 int = 2018

Select Top (@R2-@R1+1) 
       N=@R1-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
 From  master..spt_values n1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tally table or CTE like:

```
DECLARE @MinYear AS INT = 2010;
DECLARE @MaxYear AS INT = 2018;
WITH NumbersCTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Num1.Num) -1 As Num
    from (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS Num1(num)
    CROSS JOIN 
        (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS Num2(num)

)
SELECT @MinYear + Num
FROM NumbersCTE
WHERE @MinYear + Num <= @MaxYear
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:** This is also a another way using `GOTO`

```
CREATE TABLE #EData(Edata INT)

DECLARE @Min INT=2010, @Max INT=2018, @curValue INT

GenerateNumber:

SELECT @curValue = MAX(EData) FROM #EData
INSERT INTO #EData
SELECT ISNULL(@curValue, @Min-1)+1

IF (SELECT MAX(EData) FROM #Edata) < @Max
GOTO GenerateNumber

SELECT * FROM #EData
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Edata
-----
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
```